# Why doesn't Xamarin's Java.Lang.Object class override ToString()?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was debugging a Xamarin Java bindings library recently and found out that while the `Java.Lang.Object` class have a `ToString()` method, it does not actually override `object.ToString()`. Instead, its `ToString()` method simply hides the inherited method. This means that when I view a Java class that overrides `toString()` in the VS debugger, all that shows up is the name of the managed C# type.

Why doesn't `Java.Lang.Object` override `object.ToString()` and have it forward to its new `ToString()` method? (Similar question for `object.Equals()` and `object.GetHashCode()`, too.)